# what does mean that $A^TPA+P=I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Question was

Let $$A= \left[\begin{matrix} 
        a_1 & a_2\\
         a_3&a_4\\
       \end{matrix}\right]$$
$$P= \left[\begin{matrix} 
        p_1 & p_2\\
         p_3&p_4\\
       \end{matrix}\right]$$

Find the matrix $Q$ such that

$$ Q\left[
    \begin{array}
      \\
      p_1\\p_3\\p_2\\p_4
    \end{array}
\right] = \left[
    \begin{array}
      \\
      1\\0\\0\\1
    \end{array}
\right]$$ is equivalent to the equation $A^TPA+P=I$

In this question I approached to make $Q$ to $2\times 2$ matrix. but I couldn't get any idea.. I need you genius to help.